# How to create a Look At Matrix in C for OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

**EDIT:** The issue was something that I hadnt shown, I made another change to my code so I was only assigning the projection matrix uniform once before the render loop. Thank you to @Rabbid76 for attempting to assist me! Also, I do not know how to close this question...

I have been following along with the LearnOpenGL tutorial and working with GLFW in C and recreating a lot of the functions that GLM provides. I had successful 3d rendering up until I got to the camera portion of the tutorial. If I could get some pointers on where I went wrong I would really appreciate it.

Here is my GLM lookat function attempt:

```
void makeLookAtMatrix(struct v3 eye, struct v3 target, struct v3 up, struct mat4* viewMat) {


  struct mat4 dirMat;

  struct v3 X, Y, Z;

  subtractVectors(eye, target, &Z);
  normalize3d(&Z);
  Y = up;
  crossProduct(Y, Z, &X);
  crossProduct(Z, X, &Y);
  normalize3d(&X);
  normalize3d(&Y);

  float dotX;
  float dotY;
  float dotZ;
  dotProduct(X, eye, &dotX);
  dotProduct(Y, eye, &dotY);
  dotProduct(Z, eye, &dotZ);

  dirMat.m[0][0] = X.x;
  dirMat.m[0][1] = X.y;
  dirMat.m[0][2] = X.z;
  dirMat.m[1][0] = Y.x;
  dirMat.m[1][1] = Y.y;
  dirMat.m[1][2] = Y.z;
  dirMat.m[2][0] = Z.x;
  dirMat.m[2][1] = Z.y;
  dirMat.m[2][2] = Z.z;
  dirMat.m[0][3] = -1.0f * dotX;
  dirMat.m[1][3] = -1.0f * dotY;
  dirMat.m[2][3] = -1.0f * dotZ;
  dirMat.m[3][0] = 0;
  dirMat.m[3][1] = 0;
  dirMat.m[3][2] = 0;
  dirMat.m[3][3] = 1.0f;

  *viewMat = dirMa
}
```

Related functions:

```
void crossProduct(struct v3 vec1, struct v3 vec2, struct v3* returnVec) {
  returnVec->x = (vec1.y * vec2.z) - (vec1.z * vec2.y);
  returnVec->y = (vec1.z * vec2.x) - (vec1.x * vec2.z);
  returnVec->z = (vec1.x * vec2.y) - (vec1.y * vec2.x);
}

void dotProduct(struct v3 vec1, struct v3 vec2, float *result) {
  *result = (vec1.x * vec2.x) + (vec1.y * vec2.y) + (vec1.z * vec2.z);
}

void normalize3d(struct v3* vec) {
  float dotProduct = vec->x * vec->x + vec->y * vec->y + vec->z * vec->z;
  float magnitude = sqrt(dotProduct);

  if (magnitude != 0.0) {
    vec->x /= magnitude;
    vec->y /= magnitude;
    vec->z /= magnitude;
  }
}
```

Use in render loop:

```
struct v3 yAxis = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
struct mat4 view;
struct v3 cameraVec = {0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f};
struct v3 cameraTarget = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

makeLookAtMatrix(cameraVec, cameraTarget, yAxis, &view);
```

Previous view matrix:

```
struct mat4 view = makeIdentityMatrix();
struct v3 cameraVec = {0.0f, -2.0f, -10.0f};
translate(cameraVec, &view);
```

Ive tried a couple different approaches for the lookat matrix, this has been the simplest and I can't seem to  find an issue in my code unless I just dont understand the math. Currently no shapes are being rendered to the screen, whereas when the previous view matrix rendered everything as I expected.

Comment: I suggest using [OpenGL Mathematics (glm) for C](https://github.com/recp/cglm?tab=readme-ov-file#-opengl-mathematics-glm-for-c)

Comment: @Rabbid76 The idea of this is to learn what GLM is doing behind the scenes, if I can't recreate it, then I don't truly understand it.

Comment: The view matrix appears to be transposed. OpenGL matrices are usually stored with column-major order.

Comment: I have GLBoolean transpose set to GL_TRUE here:
'glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_TRUE, &view.m);'
which worked before,  I tried changing it to GL_FALSE and it did not fix it.

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_camera.html#lookat

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) the `gluLookAt` just construct such matrix from know position and 2 directions (view direction is Z axis and the other two are perpendicular to `Z` and "aligned" to `Up`   exploiting  cross product ... its more or less the same math as rotating around arbitrary axis `glRotate` (just without the rotation and converting back)